# Is there any text completion ide for corona SDK?

Tags: autocomplete, ide, lua, coronasdk

I am looking for an IDE with text completion feature. Like in Visual Studio.

I am coding in lua using the Corona SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Go to [Corona third-party tools](http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/3rd-party-tools-and-services/), filter by IDE; most of those IDEs provide auto-complete.